# Mac Mini considers downloaded files to be undownloaded?

Tags: icloud, finder

I was recently trying to move files between users using the Applications folder as a proxy, but now that the files are back in their original location, most of them have a cloud icon with an exclamation mark next to their name. Trying to delete some of these files brings up a bubble stating that the file "needs to be downloaded" despite the fact that it *is* downloaded. How can I fix this bug (or at least circumvent it?)

Comment: What OS version? Do you use iCloud Drive's "Documents and Desktop"? What locations are you moving them from? Have you restarted? (In future, I would suggest using `/Users/Shared`, rather than `/Applications`, though.)

Comment: I'm on 14.1.2, the latest version as of writing this. Yes, from iCloud Drive Desktop, yes, and thanks, I didn't know that `/Users/Shared` was a thing!